# Amazone aws KVS Video streaming without cognito in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want using Amazon KVS Video Streaming Service without Cognito.

I only have Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.

Is it possible to make this without Cognito ?

I am following below reference.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-ios.html
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-ios

Comment: I was wondering the same. The test app allows it, yet Android and iOS SDK doesn't. It would be very helpful if that would be possible for Android and iOS too.
https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js/examples/index.html